# Identify the song featuring in Apple's WWDC 2015 intro video?

Tags: identify-this-song, soundtrack

See [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H1C9BeyD_e0) link. Go to 3:10 position. Also 3:22 because may be it is different song.

It is the introduction video of Apple's WWDC 2015 keynote presentation.
I love that song and I've tried to find it but I couldn't.

Comment: Where is the MP3 ?  Also, pls describe the music in terms of what instruments, what style of music. thanks

Comment: The youtube video <https://youtu.be/_p8AsQhaVKI> only starts with Tim Cook's entrance, which according to timeline here <http://www.macrumors.com/2015/06/08/wwdc-2015-live-coverage/> is at 10:07, so 7 minutes after start.    I can't find any music at 3:30 on the youtube video.

Comment: I will get soon with the link having intro video..,thanks all for being in contact ...

Comment: Can u try to find wwdc 2015 video having intro before Tim Cook enters??

Comment: From the lyrics of the rap, it sounds to me like it was written specifically for that Apple sketch.

Comment: Thanks @topomorto, can you move to 3:22 ? It seems to be some song rather than Apple made.. Here is the [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H1C9BeyD_e0)

Comment: (notice how those lyrics repeat those from the sketch at 3:06)

Comment: I think Apple should jump into Music industry as well..

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_Corps_v_Apple_Computer - "as a condition of the settlement, Apple Computer agreed not to enter the music business, and Apple Corps agreed not to enter the computer business."

Comment: Great topo-morto..you seems to be great in music. You should enter in music industry I think..

Comment: Not much help for your question, but the singer/performer is the actor Danny Pudi https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Danny_Pudi, known from community. He is not known for making music before, but maybe you can contact him through a social media profile and ask about this...

Answer (score 2):

It seems very much like the whole thing is written specially as part of the sketch, including both the rap at 3:10 and the song at 3.22, which both have lyrics referencing apple products:

- The [App Store](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/App_Store_%28iOS%29)
- [Swift](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swift_%28programming_language%29)
- [Objective-C](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Objective-C)

The only place I could find the lyrics on the web are [here](https://tw.voicetube.com/videos/print/27610), which is a script for this sketch.

> David, Why did I want to direct the WWDC opening number?
>   Good question.
>   You know, I think I've always been attracted to risk.
>   You know?
>   When I shared my vision for the number, um, you know, they said,
>   Hey, this is just a developer's conference, you know.
>   you don't need to overthink it.
>   but I always feel that my job as a director
>   is to push an idea.
>   What's that? Am I a genius?
>   I don't know -- What?
>   Stage Manager: Hey David, you ready for the walkthrough?
>   David: Yeah.
>   Stage Manager: Who are you talking to in here?
>   David: No one. Shh.
>   Stage Manager: You were talking to somebody,
>   unless you were talking to yourself.
>   Dana: I've been working on this new app called "Work Crush."
>   It's for people who have crushes on their workmates
>   and want to know when they're nearby.
>   It's not for me, but... PHONE CHIMES
>   Oh, hi David!
>   David: Yeah, I thought you were supposed
>   to be guarding my door.
>   Dana: Which one's your door?
>   BELL RINGING
>   David: What is this? Rick! Rick, look at me.
>   I need you angry in there, Rick.
>   I need you angry, angry, angry!
>   Yeah!
>   Alright, did you get that email about my email not working?
>   Dana: No.
>   David: What? No, no, no!
>   It needs to be more, you know, like WHOOSH!
>   Dana: Yeah, he means bigger.
>   David: Bigger, bigger, yeah, like developers are on fire!
>   Runner: Which iPhone do you want for the main character,
>   silver or gold?
>   David: Let me see silver.
>   Let me see gold.
>   Let me see silver.
>   Let me see gold.
>   See I can't tell because
>   the reflection of the flame is on it,
>   and I can't ...
>   Fire Marshall: Can you decide this later?
>   David: Yeah, he's right. Let's decide it later.
>   Dana: We'll take the gold.
>   Got to choose the talent for the dating app number.
>   David: Yes.
>   No.
>   Yes.
>   No.
>   Yeah.
>   The pretty one.
>   Runner: That's you.
>   David: Whoa!
>   Did you do this?
>   Dana: Yeah!
>   David: Oh my gosh, that's my coffee!
>   Dana: Yeah!
>   David: Oh, cool!
>   Oh, that's awesome.
>   Did you bring my sugar or anything?
>   SCREAMS
>   Who are these guys?
>   Dana: The Tim Cook-a-likes you asked for.
>   David: Oh, right.
>   Hey, you guys are good to get wet, right?
>   Woman: Hey!
>   David: Oh, hey, you guys are the faces of WWDC.
>   Let's go!
>   Let's give it all.
>   Well, not the real faces,
>   you're the masks that they give you.
>   What's this?
>   Dana: Goat Simulator.
>   David: Goat Simulator, I'm not feeling it, kill it.
>   Alright ... Oh, that's an axe!
>   No, no, no, don't ... Don't actually kill it, okay?
>   There he is! Hey!
>   Angel Investor: David, what have you got me into here?
>   Am I like a Victoria's Secrets guy?
>   David: You are an angel investor.
>   You make millions off kids' dreams.
>   Angel Investor: So I'm just a rich guy?
>   David: You're a rich guy.
>   Bring him up!
>   Angel Investor: This harness cuts the circulation off
>   in my legs.
>   David: Oh, that's alright buddy, no worries.
>   SCREAMING
>   Choreographer: OK, let's run it.
>   David: No, no, no, I say when we run it.
>   Who is that? Why is he saying my words?
>   Choreographer: Run it. David: Thank you.
>   Developer: SINGING ♪ So many days of dev time!
>   ♪ Haven't seen a ray of sunshine!
>   ♪ Locked in my coding lair!
>   ♪ It's been days since I changed my underwear!
>   ♪ My app is in the store!
>   Backup Singers: ♪ Your app is in the store!
>   Developer: RAPPING **♪ From the white board
>
>   ♪ to the App Store,
>
>   ♪ 'cause when I code, I'm Swift, boy.
>
>   ♪ Yeah. I rule Objective-C.
>
>   ♪ Objective one? Objective me.
>
>   ♪ See that app? I made that.
>
>   ♪ Download my game? You played that.
>
>   ♪ After today, now I'm worldwide.
>
>   ♪ Five stars. Now watch me shine.
>
>   SINGING : ♪ *You made the cut. The world is yours.
>
>   ♪ Now that your app is in the store.
>
>   ♪ This is your break, your time to fly.
>
>   ♪ So reach your hands up and touch the sky*. ♪**
>   CRASHING
>   David: What happened?
>   Electrician: The generator's blown.
>   David: Damn it!
>   Well, can I at least get a work light?
>   Stage Manager: Rebooting!
>   APPLE CHIME
>   David: How long until we're up and running?
>   Stage Manager: I don't know, maybe 24 hours?
>   David: Well, what am I supposed to do with this?
>   Guys, we go live tomorrow.
>   That's just a bottle of water and a laptop.
>   Dana: I don't know.
>   I think it's kind of pretty.
>   ♪ Music playing ♪
>   David: Alright, we'll work with it.
>   I'll tell you what though, whoever walks out there
>   better have something pretty incredible to say.
>   Dana: Yeah, I just hope he doesn't get booed.
>   David: Either way, we're getting free Watches out of it.
>   ♪